# Strange item spacing in ConTeXt

Tags: spacing, lists, context, itemize

This input:

```
\starttext
  \startitemize
    \item foo
      \startitemize
        \item bar
        \item baz
      \stopitemize
      some more text here
  \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

Renders like:

[image]

It seems strange that there is space before the items in the second itemize, but not afterwards. I tried this:

```
\starttext
  \startitemize
    \item foo
      \startitemize[nowhite]
        \item bar
        \item baz
      \stopitemize
      some more text here
  \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

This removed the space between the items, but not that before them. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `paragraph` option to the higher level itemize:

```
\starttext
  \startitemize[paragraph]
    \item foo
      \startitemize
        \item bar
        \item baz
      \stopitemize
      some more text here
  \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image]